# how to reuse test methods in testng which can take data from multiple data providers

Tags: java, testng

Im new to testng and my Requirement is follows:

I have 5 Test Methods and I have 2 test scenarios and 2 data providers.
Scenario 1: this will use Dataprovider1 and run all 5 test methods.
Scenario 2: this will use Data provider2 and run 3 test methods among 5.

Please suggest solution to above problem using testng.

I'm just Editing it to be more clear with two methods. 
With DP1 -- Execute two Test Methods
With DP2 -- Execute two Test Methods.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP")
public static void testCompanyId(Map mp){
    AssertJUnit.assertNotNull(mp.get("id"));        
}
@Test(dataProvider = "DP")
public static void testName(Map mp){
    AssertJUnit.assertNotNull(mp.get("name"));  
}

@DataProvider(name = "DP")
public static Object[][] Create(){
    String name="abc";
            String id="12fd123d43r43fd4";
            Map<String,String> inputMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            mp.put("name", name);
            mp.put("id", id);
    return new Object[][]{{inputMap}};
 }
@DataProvider(name = "DP")
public static Object[][] Get(){
    String name="xyz";
            String id=null;                
            mp.put("name", name);
            mp.put("id", id);

    return new Object[][]{{inputMap}};
}
```

TIA

Comment: I'm not very experienced with TDD, but I'd use mocks-dataproviders for tests (unless what you're trying to test are *actualy* the data providers).

Comment: well if your data providers are objects of the same class you don't need to make 2 test suits, if there are NOT from same class you need to make 2 suits, its redundant to make same tests on the same object multiple times, if you do need a repeated action make a test that tests repeated behaviour

Answer (score 0):

i'm a bit unclear on the question, but you can make both data providers regular methods then combine them in the actual @DataProvider

---

Edit:

Looking at the code and if you wanted to execute both tests with both data providers, why not just do:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "DP")
public static void test(String name, String id){
    AssertJUnit.assertNotNull(mp.get("id"));
    AssertJUnit.assertNotNull(mp.get("name"));          
}

@DataProvider(name = "DP")
public static Object[][] params(){
    return new Object[][]{   { "abc", "12fd123d43r43fd4" },
                             { "xyz", null };
}
```

Also not sure if having two data providers with the same name is a good idea.

Since I am still a bit unclear on the question, you can also return two hashmaps as objects if that's what you are trying to do.

```
@DataProvider(name = "DP")
public static Object[][] params(){
    String name="abc";
            String id="12fd123d43r43fd4";
            Map<String,String> inputMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            mp.put("name", name);
            mp.put("id", id);

            //create inputMap2


    return new Object[][]{{inputMap1},{inputMap2};
 }
```

Comment: pls suggest how to combine two data providers. Two methods may not be returning the same kind of data to test method but input variables are same